# Matomo does not work with Rails and webpacker

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, matomo

Matomo has stopped tracking page visits for a Rails site of mine that I recently upgraded to use Webpacker.

When I experimentally create a file `test.html` on a private site and copy/paste the tracking code from my production Rails site to it, tracking does not work either:

```js
!function(e){var t={};function n(r){if(t[r])return t[r].exports;var o=t[r]={i:r,l:!1,exports:{}};return e[r].call(o.exports,o,o.exports,n),o.l=!0,o.exports}n.m=e,n.c=t,n.d=function(e,t,r){n.o(e,t)||Object.defineProperty(e,t,{enumerable:!0,get:r})},n.r=function(e){"undefined"!==typeof Symbol&&Symbol.toStringTag&&Object.defineProperty(e,Symbol.toStringTag,{value:"Module"}),Object.defineProperty(e,"__esModule",{value:!0})},n.t=function(e,t){if(1&t&&(e=n(e)),8&t)return e;if(4&t&&"object"===typeof e&&e&&e.__esModule)return e;var r=Object.create(null);if(n.r(r),Object.defineProperty(r,"default",{enumerable:!0,value:e}),2&t&&"string"!=typeof e)for(var o in e)n.d(r,o,function(t){return e[t]}.bind(null,o));return r},n.n=function(e){var t=e&&e.__esModule?function(){return e.default}:function(){return e};return n.d(t,"a",t),t},n.o=function(e,t){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,t)},n.p="/packs/",n(n.s=33)}({33:function(e,t){var n,r=window._paq||[];r.push(["setCookieDomain","*.MY_RAILS_SITE"]),r.push(["setDomains",["*.MY_RAILS_SITE","*.MY_RAILS_SITE"]]),r.push(["disableCookies"]),r.push(["trackPageView"]),r.push(["enableLinkTracking"]),function(){var e="https://matomo.MY_MATOMO_HOST/";r.push(["setTrackerUrl",e+"matomo.php"]),r.push(["setSiteId","2"]);var t=document,n=t.createElement("script"),o=t.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];n.type="text/javascript",n.async=!0,n.defer=!0,n.src=e+"matomo.js",o.parentNode.insertBefore(n,o)}(),n=null,addEventListener("turbolinks:load",(function(e){n&&(r.push(["setReferrerUrl",n]),r.push(["setCustomUrl",window.location.href]),r.push(["setDocumentTitle",document.title]),e.data&&e.data.timing&&r.push(["setGenerationTimeMs",e.data.timing.visitEnd-e.data.timing.visitStart]),r.push(["trackPageView"])),n=window.location.href}))}});
```

However, when I take the script directly from my sources (and not from the production site) and place it into the `test.html` file, tracking works!

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <p>Hello</p>
  <!-- Matomo -->
    <script>
    var _paq = window._paq || [];
    /* tracker methods like "setCustomDimension" should be called before "trackPageView" */
    _paq.push(["setCookieDomain", "*.MY_RAILS_SITE"]);
    _paq.push(["setDomains", ["*.MY_RAILS_SITE","*.MY_RAILS_SITE"]]);
    _paq.push(["disableCookies"]);
    _paq.push(['trackPageView']);
    _paq.push(['enableLinkTracking']);
    (function() {
      var u="https://matomo.MY_MATOMO_HOST/";
      _paq.push(['setTrackerUrl', u+'matomo.php']);
      _paq.push(['setSiteId', '2']);
      var d=document, g=d.createElement('script'), s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      g.type='text/javascript'; g.async=true; g.defer=true; g.src=u+'matomo.js'; s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s);
    })();
    <!-- End Matomo Code -->
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

(Host names redacted for privacy.)

Evidently, the code gets changed when deploying to production in a way that prevents it from working.

There are no errors in the browser console whatsoever, no trouble with content-security headers etc., and the `matomo.js` script loads properly, with a HTTP 200 result.

What's going on here?

Comment: I do not know what the issue is but I just noticed this myself, it appears something changed in Firefox recently to break this but do not know what to do to narrow it down. I'm on slightly older version of Matomo.  It still works in Chrome.

Comment: Glad to see that I am not alone. Btw my daily driver is Vivaldi, which is Chromium-based, and tracking does not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

It seems I have finally gotten it to work again. Looking closely at the JavaScript snippet that Matomo suggests for new sites. I spotted some subtle differences.

```
- var _paq = window._paq || [];
+ var _paq = window._paq = window._paq || [];
  /* tracker methods like "setCustomDimension" should be called before "trackPageView" */
  _paq.push(["setCookieDomain", "*.MY_RAILS_SITE"]);
  _paq.push(["setDomains", ["*.MY_RAILS_SITE","*.MY_RAILS_SITE"]]);
  _paq.push(["disableCookies"]);
  _paq.push(['trackPageView']);
  _paq.push(['enableLinkTracking']);
  (function() {
    var u="https://matomo.MY_MATOMO_HOST/";
    _paq.push(['setTrackerUrl', u+'matomo.php']);
    _paq.push(['setSiteId', '2']);
    var d=document, g=d.createElement('script'), 
   s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
-  g.type='text/javascript'; g.async=true; g.defer=true; g.src=u+'matomo.js'; s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s);
+  g.type='text/javascript'; g.async=true; g.src=u+'matomo.js'; 
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s);
  })();


  // From https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/issues/436#issuecomment-456862864
  // Send Matomo a new event when navigating to a new page using Turbolinks
  // (see https://developer.matomo.org/guides/spa-tracking)
  (function() {
    var previousPageUrl = null;
    addEventListener('turbolinks:load', function(event) {
      if (previousPageUrl) {
+       var _paq = window._paq = window._paq || [];
        _paq.push(['setReferrerUrl', previousPageUrl]);
        _paq.push(['setCustomUrl', window.location.href]);
        _paq.push(['setDocumentTitle', document.title]);
```

The `_paq` variable is assigned differently, and the working snippet is missing the `g.defer=true` bit. Additionally, `_paq` is now assigned in the Turbolinks event handler.